# Should I containerize a standalone command-line or terminal application which requires 16 vCPU?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, docker, containers, cluster-computing

We are using an application which is currently compiled for windows (it is a standalone .exe, not hooked into registry) and which can also be cross-compiled for *nix if needed. This application runs optimally using about 16 threads in parallel.

Deploying an entire windows (or Linux) stack seems burdensome and heavy but I don't understand if containers make sense. ***Where I am confused is that I THOUGHT containers would run on Azure or AWS basically on a shim of some sort.*** What it looks like is that, instead, I need to spin up a host virtual machine to hold containers. If that is true, then I can only put two containers on a 32 vCPU and containers don't make sense (I think).

Hopefully I am just misunderstanding this. *Is there anything lightweight out there which can let me run a process which does heavy computation and file I/O (result files are 16gb+ each) but doesn't rely a GUI, etc?*

With all the advertisement out there for docker / swarm, core-os, kubernetes, mesos / mesosphere, I am really cornfused.

Answer (score 1):

Your application is similar to work we've done to support parallel execution of Office File conversion, using Microsoft's converter.   We run the converter to support ppt to mp4 conversion, with multiple containers each with a fairly large cpu allocation.   The container design on WinDocks is lighter-weight, as it doesn't include OS files.   You can give it a try using the free Community Edition, at [WinDocks.com](http://www.windocks.com/lps/communityedition)

*Disclosure: I am the Co-Founder of WinDocks*